# pyplot.figure Отображение картины в точном месте на экране

Tags: python-2.7, matplotlib

Создаю *figure*:

```
fig = pyplot.figure(figsize= (Width, Height))
```

Размер *Width* и *Height* удаётся задать, а вот расположение на экране нет.

Я запускаю программу, передвигаю окно c картинкой в удобное место на экране,
потом выхожу из программы, при этом запоминая размер картинки и её расположение.

Далее я хочу чтобы при новом запуске программы, окно появилось в том удобном месте, с заданной шириной и высотой.

Comment: посмотри мой [самоответ](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/742969/227016) по этой теме. он не является полным ответом на твой вопрос, но может помочь