# Задать координаты окна, полученного с помощью matplotlib

Tags: python, matplotlib

Моя программа использует matplotlib для отображения графиков на экране. Как я могу задать координаты окна с графиками, которое появляется при этом?

Графики я рисую примерно так:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

plt.figure()
plt.plot([1, 2, 3], [2, 4, 8])
plt.show()
```

Comment: ассоциация: https://stackoverflow.com/q/7449585/5812238

Comment: @VasylKolomiets, это самответ)) я сам спросил и сам ответил) принять свой ответ можно не ранее чем через два дня после задания вопроса

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ответ отличается в зависимости от используемого [бекенда](https://matplotlib.org/faq/usage_faq.html#what-is-a-backend). Во всех примерах вместо `x` и `y` нужно подставить желаемые абсолютные координаты окна.

- TkAgg:

  ```
  plt.get_current_fig_manager().window.wm_geometry('+x+y')
  ```
- WXAgg:

  ```
  plt.get_current_fig_manager().window.SetPosition((x, y))
  ```
- Qt:

  ```
  plt.get_current_fig_manager().window.move(x, y)
  ```

  либо, предварительно получив высоту и ширину окна:

  ```
  # x_old и y_old --- старые координаты окна, их значения не используются
  x_old, y_old, width, height = plt.get_current_fig_manager().window.geometry().getRect()
  plt.get_current_fig_manager().window.setGeometry(x, y, width, height)
  ```